# Specify CSS's for webkit/IE without separate CSS

Tags: css, webkit

For IE I can use this:

```
.content {
   *padding: 10px;
   padding: 10px
}
```

By doing so, the *-part will only be used for IE. Is there a tric like this for webkit browsers too? (Whitout having them called to a special .css for webkit browsers?)

Comment: Why do you need such a hack for WebKit browsers?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to use different stylesheets (yes, I know, it's silly, but I don't make te rules)

Comment: It's generally recommended these days not to use CSS hacks like these, see http://www.digital-web.com/articles/keep_css_simple/

Comment: Ok, here's a better question, "Why would you need different style-sheets for Webkit?"  AFAIK, Webkit is pretty compliant with modern standards.

Comment: You don't need hacks to make modern markup work in Chrome, or any of the modern browsers. Only IE needs such things, as implied by the two above.

Comment: As a matter of fact, Chrome does need it :) Don't ask me why, it's not my code. But with the hack I wrote downhere, it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a new way instead of using get_browser() for those who doesn't have the extension installed. This new way is by using HTACCESS instead. You need the module "mod_setenvif" installed.

Here is the code you need to put in the .htaccess file.
It's a regexp over the HTTP_USER_AGENT server variable. If it matches, we create a USER_AGENT variable to store the matching browser name.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
BrowserMatch "Mozilla" USER_AGENT=firefox
BrowserMatch "Safari" USER_AGENT=safari
BrowserMatch "Chrome" USER_AGENT=chrome
BrowserMatch "MSIE" USER_AGENT=ie
</IfModule>
```

Then, you can use the new server variable in your PHP code.

```
<body class="<?php echo $_SERVER['USER_AGENT'];?>">
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Creative, but can't you just grep `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` within your PHP code anyway? No need for an .htaccess that depends on some Apache module.

Comment: This idea was to avoid a PHP function to write. But, at the end you might be right because it remains the same amount of job in both case.
Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's not such a hack for webkit-based browsers. However, you *can* achieve such an effect (in multiple browsers) using:

```
<script>
(function(){ //anonymous function to prevent leaking
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.style.cssText = "-webkit-border-radius:1px;"; // webkit, such as Chrome/Safari
  if(/webkit/i.test(d.style.cssText)){
      var style = document.createElement("style");
      style.src = "webkit-only.css";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
  }
})();
</script>
```

The key behind this solution is that unknown CSS declarations are ignored by a browser. The `-webkit-` prefix will only be available in webkit-based browsers.

Similarly, the following prefixes can be used to detect other browser engines:

- `-moz-border-radius:1px;` - Gecko, such as Firefox
- `-o-border-radius:0;` - Opera
- `-ms-border-radius:0;` - Trident, such as Internet Explorer

There's a chance that your user has an ancient browser which don't support `border-radius`, but since Chrome is usually kept up-to-date (auto-update), the `webkit` solution should always work.

Answer (score 1):

Found a decent hack. Seems to work at first sight :)

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     div.panel-homepage div#plan-build-operate div.panel-pane ul.links a { padding-top: 20px;}
}
```

Comment: If you need to adjust the `padding-top` on some links *for only WebKit* browsers, you're *doing it wrong*. I can't tell you what you're doing wrong because you haven't shown your page.

Comment: The thing wrong is that all modern browsers have simple things such as `padding` consistent between them. As I said, if you need to change the `padding-top` for only WebKit browsers, it's likely that something is wrong with your page, not WebKit. To be honest, this seems like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok, I get your point. It's a Drupal website, so I think there is indeed something wrong with the page. But, with the hack, it's solved, so for now, it's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with PHP, there is a function call :

**get_browser()**

check at : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-browser.php

This function returns an array of all the information about the client browser. 
Add these informations as CSS class in your body tag.

You will be able to target specific browser without using CSS hack and
have a valid CSS code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to target Webkit:

```
x:-webkit-any-link { padding: 10px; }
```

If you need to support IE7, add the following to filter this rule from applying to it:

```
 * > /**/ .content, x:-webkit-any-link { padding: 10px; }
```